# Does anyone know how to change SERB NPDF user profile?

Tags: postdocs

Its really important for me. I applied for SERB NPDF this year and for that I used my institute's mail ID. But as I completed my degree, the institute is changing the Mail domain to an alumni one and I will not receive any further mail to my current account. So, basically I will not be getting any updates from SERB. Please help me finding a solution. Is there anyway one can change the user ID details which is a mail id? I am in desperate need of it.

Comment: Have you asked SERB?

Comment: Yes I have asked them. They told to wait for sometime. I don't know how this will go.